# execute javascript code in views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with AngularJS, and I have an index page, in this page I have a `<div ui-view></div>`.
when I type some url for example `#/offers/new` I call a page e.g. `new-offer.html` which will be injected in the `ui-view`.

And I have a javascript code block which I call in the `index.html` page, in this javascript code I want to do some html handling and the html code I want to handle is in the `new-offer.html page.

so here is what happens, when I load `index.html` it executes the javascript code which doesn't find the html code to handle in the the index.html, and then when I call `#/offers/new` the `new-offer.html` will be injected and nothing will happen.

this is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
...

  <div ui-view></div>

  ... Code
  ... Other scripts
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<!--TEXT EDITOR JS-->
 <script src="scripts/js/editor.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

and this is `new-offer.html`:

```
... Code
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-editor-box">
              <textarea class="txtEditor"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
... Code
```

and this is the script I call in the `index.html` and I want it to be executed when I call `#/offers/new` :

```
//TEXT EDITOR
    if ($('.txtEditor').length) {
    $(".txtEditor").Editor();
    }
```

isn't there anyway to solve this without calling the javascript code inside the `new-offer.html` page ? I mean to not execute that javascript code until I inject the html code inside `new-offer.html` into `index.html`.

## Edit 1:

I tried to use directives as following :

in app.js :

```
.directive('textEditordir', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div class="text-editor-box"><textarea class="txtEditor"></textarea></div>'
  };
});
```

and in `new-offer.html` :

```
<div text-editordir></div>
```

but still, the javascript code didn't work

Comment: You didn't mention what the code does, but generally speaking - if you want to work with the DOM in AngularJS you should probably use Directives. Read about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @AdirAmsalem please check the modifications I made

Comment: Generally, JQuery works out of the box. Try angular.element to create own DOM manipulations. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngJq https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element what you are trying might not be directly possible. Try directives or alternate methods in route, config definitions

Comment: Try resolve, onEnter, onExit etc... https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: Saw the edit. Do you get an error?

Comment: Ok, did you try instantiation of JQuery from within Link or compile Like Sailendra mentioned? Can you put the plunkr for the code?

Answer (score 1):

you can create directive for this like as-

```
app.directive('editor', function(){
 return{
     restrict:'A',
     link:function(scope,element,attr)
             {
              $(element).Editor();
             }

}

});
```

now you can use this on html as-

```
 <textarea class="txtEditor" editor></textarea>
```

Comment: I tried this and I get that  $ is not a function, even when I have declared jQuery before calling the app.js

Comment: try with out using $ sign like as - element.Editor();

Comment: no need to use `$(element)` when jQuery.js loaded in page before angular.js. The `element` will already be jQuery object